# Closing Laptop Lid Causes Hibernation with Xmonad

Tags: 13.10, suspend, xmonad

I use Xmonad. When I close my laptop, the computer goes to sleep. I would like to stop this. I want the computer to continue operating normally when the lid closes. I use Ubuntu 13.10. Any advice?

`la /etc/acpi/` returns:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  391 Oct  9  2012 asus-keyboard-backlight.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  180 Oct  9  2012 asus-wireless.sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Oct 23 18:59 events
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  608 Oct  9  2012 ibm-wireless.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.2K Aug 16 10:54 powerbtn.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  455 Oct  9  2012 tosh-wireless.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  238 Oct  9  2012 undock.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

you could solve it by editing some things in `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` file

first take a backup just if something happen to restore later

```
sudo cp /etc/acpi/lid.sh /etc/acpi/lid.sh.BAK
```

open /etc/acpi/lid.sh and find this line

```
/usr/share/acpi-support/screenblank
```

and replace it with

```
 echo -n mem > /sys/power/state
```

logout and then login and try

Comment: Thanks for your help. Currently, I do not seem to have this file. I have updated my question with `/etc/acpi/`'s contents. Should I create a `lid.sh` file and add the line you suggest?